# VBA - Message Box appearing after a Login Screen

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I am currently building a DB in which the database tables and forms that appear are based upon the user permissions. If the user does not have permissions to the database then a message box will appear stating that "You do not have access to this database." This code is executed within a login screen where the  user only has to press a login button. The problem that I am having is that when the user does have permissions the message box will still appear. Once the users interacts with the message box they are then redirected to their corresponding form. I would like for this message box to appear only if the user does not have permissions and once they interact with the message box the DB will then close. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Debug.Print Environ("UserName")
Debug.Print Environ$("ComputerName")

Dim strVar As String
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 255
    strVar = Environ$(i)
    If LenB(strVar) = 0& Then Exit For
    Debug.Print strVar
Next

Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblUser", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs.FindFirst "UserName = '" & EmployeeType_ID & "'"

If rs.NoMatch = True Then
    MsgBox "You do not have access to this database.", vbInformation, "Access"
End If

If rs!EmployeeType_ID = 4 Then

    Dim prop As Property
    On Error GoTo SetProperty
    Set prop = CurrentDb.CreateProperty("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False)

    CurrentDb.Properties.Append prop

SetProperty:
    If MsgBox("Would you like to turn on the bypass key?", vbYesNo, "Allow Bypass") = vbYes Then
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = True
    Else
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = False
    End If

End If

If rs!EmployeeType_ID = 4 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmManager"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogin", acSaveNo
End If

If rs!EmployeeType_ID = 3 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAssistant_Manager"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogin", acSaveNo
End If

If rs!EmployeeType_ID = 2 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLead"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogin", acSaveNo
End If

If rs!EmployeeType_ID = 1 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmGeneral_User"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogin", acSaveNo
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: is username = EmployeeType_ID?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav No, their username is their windows login name. The EmployeeType_ID is a text field where the admin would assign the user permissions either 1-4 with each having their own corresponding forms.

Comment: Well that's my guess, you need to set that search to be their windows logon

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I am now able to close the database when the message box appears if the user does not permissions, but it still appears if they do have permissions. Not sure how I would set the search to be their windows logon and still set their permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem within the database. I replaced:

```
rs.FindFirst "UserName = '" & EmployeeType_ID & "'" with rs.FindFirst "UserName = '" & Environ("UserName") & "'"
```

and below my message box within the code I placed Access.Quit so when the user interacts with the message box it will then close.